# Print Authentication (Sharp MX-2640N)

Tags: drivers, printing, authentication

I am trying to set up a network printer that requires authentication. I have the problem that there is nowhere to enter the username or password.

- The printer is: Sharp MX-2640N.
- Running Ubuntu 14.04.
- CUPS 1.7.2.
- Printer driver (from
  http://www.sharp.co.uk/cps/rde/xchg/gb/hs.xsl/-/html/product-details-office-print-2373.htm?product=MX2640N)
  is: 'sharp-1.4-mx-c26-ps'

Everything installed without errors.

I have set Policies/Operating_policy to "Authenticated" (same option in printer preferences dialog and in CUPS admin config)

But this still does not cause a username/password prompt to appear at any point.

What are I doing wrong? any suggestions?